# A new Moderator Pro Tempore, cooling on the window sill

Tags: discussion, moderators

The beta is over, and Android.SE is a full-fledged member of The Stack Exchange network. By rights, you should be *electing* moderators, but instead the site is still moderated by [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). This is... somewhat unfortunate. We'd really *like* to hold elections, but... There aren't quite enough users with high reputation to pull it off just yet. We'll talk more about this later...

Fortunately, we do have some very dedicated users who've volunteered their time to do *[the pro tem thing](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)* until we've ironed out the election thing. So I am pleased to announce that a new member has stepped up and generously volunteered his time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Matthew Read]

...joins [the existing pro tem mods](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Comment: Well done Matthew!

Answer (score 4):

Awesome! Welcome to the team Matthew!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats Matthew! Glad to have you working with us!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all, I'm glad to be able to contribute further to this site!

Answer (score 3):

Congrats Matthew. Looking forward to your participation!